# powershell concatenate string with output of get-childitem

Tags: powershell

I want to add a path string to all file names returned by get-childitem from a folder.

I have tried something like

```
    Get-ChildItem  C:\path\folder |'different path' + {$}
```

I want to add a different path to all the file anmes returned from the folder. But it won't compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
Get-ChildItem -Name C:\path\folder | foreach {"different path $_"}
```

Answer (score 2):

or this:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\temp -file | select @{N="Name";E={"different path {0}" -f $_.Name}}
```

Comment: works but i will give the correct answer to the first one.

Answer (score 1):

try it:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\temp -file | %{"different path {0}" -f $_.Name}
```